# How do I call a block in a phtml instead of through a layout?

Tags: magento

I have disabled layout for the wishlist block:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtoto" as="addtoto" template="catalog/product/view/addto.phtml"/>
```

I now want to call that block in the phtml instead of add it to another layout.

How do I call it directly?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

While Prattski is correct that this is poor form (am I'm upvoting as such), there have been times when developing when either this has been a valuable debugging technique, or it made the difference of several hours of programming. In that spirit, this is the bad habit way of doing it:

```
<?php print $this->getLayout()
                 ->createBlock("catalog/product_view")
                 ->setTemplate("catalog/product/view/addto.phtml")
                 ->toHtml(); ?>
```

Use sparingly, if at all.

Answer (score 12):

```
 echo  Mage::app()->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('somemodule/someblock')
        ->setSomeVariable($variable)
        ->setTemplate('somemodule/someblock.phtml')
        ->toHtml();
```

this can be use anywhere for calling blocks. `setSomeVariable($variable)` if set can be accessed in `someblock.phtml` by `$this->getSomeVariable();`

Comment: how i can add "after" or "before" functionality to call block before some block or after some block in above code.

Comment: sorry haven't tried this one. but in createBlock the 3rd parameter is `array $attribute`. you can look into that.

Answer (score 3):

Chris - You should ever need to call a block directly from within a template.  It would be a bad habit/practice to get into.  Find the proper reference to the template you want to add the block to, and add it into the layout xml.  Then from within the template file, use:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('your-block');
```

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with this for ages and found that if you want to call a block from a totally separate part of the layout you need to use slightly different code. Use:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('any_block'); ?>
```

Instead of:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('any_block'); ?>
```

Using this code you can either create your own blocks anywhere or pick blocks from other modules and put them anywhere.

Comment: Note that it's required to define that block in layout.